# Existence of finite number of points

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f : (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} f \left(\frac{1}{2n} \right) = 2$$ and $$\lim_{n\to \infty} f \left( \frac{1}{2n+1} \right) = 1$$ Does there exist $\lambda \in (1,2)$ such that the set $\{x\in (0,1) : f(x)=\lambda\} $ is finite?

I think the IVT helps, but I can't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By IVP for every $n$ sufficiently large there is  a point $x_n \in (\frac 1 {2n+2}, \frac 1 {2n})$ such that $f(x_n)=\lambda$. And these points are distinct. So the given set is infinite.

Comment: Given $\lambda\in (1,2)$, eventually in $n$ there is a point $x_n\in \left(\frac{1}{2n+1},\frac{1}{2n}\right)$ such that $f(x_n)=\lambda$. This does not change the conclusion.

Comment: @AlessioDV Thanks for the comment. I misread the hypothesis. I have corrected the proof now.